# Python Regex Word Distance

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code in python that finds if a whole word is in a text.

```
def findWholeWord(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search
```

Now, how would be the regex to find if a word is within a range of 10 words to another, for example, suppose I have the following string:

"A Hello, World! program is a computer program that outputs "**Hello**, World!" on a display device. Being a very **simple** program in most programming languages, it is often used to illustrate to beginning programmers the basic syntax for constructing a working program. It is also used to verify that a language or system is operating correctly."

If I pass the words Hello and simple, it should match, because the number of words between them is <= 10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `(?:\W+\w+){0,10}\W+` subpattern between the two in the regex:

```
\bhello(?:\W+\w+){0,10}\W+simple\b
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lH2qE7/1)

Regex explantion:

- `\bhello` - a whole word `hello`
- `(?:\W+\w+){0,10}` - 0 to 10 sequences of one or more non-word characters followed by one or more word characters (`\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` or all Unicode letters and digits if `re.U` flag is provided) followed by...
- `\W+` - one or more non-word characters (punctuation, spaces, etc.)
- `simple\b` - a whole word `simple`

So, your code will look like

```
def findWholeWord(w1,w2):
    return re.compile(r'\b{0}(?:\W+\w+){{0,10}}\W+{1}\b'.format(w1,w2), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search
```

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/mjImbK)

**If the position of the words can be any**, you will need to add an alterantive:

```
\bhello(?:\W+\w+){0,10}\W+simple\b|\bsimple(?:\W+\w+){0,10}\W+hello\b
```

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/yL6dE4/1)

Code:

```
def findWholeWord(w1,w2):
    return re.compile(r'\b{0}(?:\W+\w+){{0,10}}\W+{1}\b|\b{1}(?:\W+\w+){{0,10}}\W+{0}\b'.format(w1,w2), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search
```

Comment: Perfect! This was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following regular expression:

```
r'\bHello\s+(\S+\s+){0,10}simple\b'
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/oL7tN8/4

Comment: `\w+\s+?` (where `\s+?` is the same as `\s+`) does not handle punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

First an assumption check.  Your findWholeWord() function returns a method not a pattern so I'm guessing it's meant to be invoked like this:

```
>>> match_result = (findWholeWord("boy"))("Oh boy how complicated!")
>>> match_result.group(0)
'boy'
```

Generally we'd return a pattern upon which we could apply different search methods.  What you've done works but locks you into one method.

Now let's discuss \b (and companion \B).  The \b operator matches a word boundary as you've discovered.  But the key concept here is what is "word".  The answer is the very narrow set [A-Za-z0-9_] -- "word" is not a natural language word but a computer language identifier.  The \b operator exists more for the language's own parser than for your use.

This means it doesn't handle common English situations like:

```
>>> match_result = (findWholeWord("won"))("I won't do it")
>>> match_result.group(0)
'won'
```

There's no simple answer that will work for all of English, whatever pattern you come up with, there will be exceptions.  You need to figure out what are the limits of the problem you're trying to solve.

Back to your original question, an approximate solution:

```
def findSeparatedWords(w1, w2, distance):
    return re.compile(r'(\b{0}\b)(\b[^\b]+\b){2}(\b{1}\b)'.format(w1, w2, "{" + str(distance) + '}'), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search

>>> match_result = (findSeparatedWords("Hello", "simple", 3))("Hello, World! is a simple computer program.")
>>> match_result
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 25), match='Hello, World! is a simple'>
>>>
>>> match_result = (findSeparatedWords("Hello", "simple", 10))("Hello, World! is a simple computer program.")
>>> match_result
>>>
```